# How to count rows to a single column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get two rows count and assign it to a single column.

```
select distinct 
    userreferenceid, 'Level(' + cast(level as varchar(255))+')' GroupLevel,
    referenceid 
from 
    (select 
         t0.userreferenceid, 
         case level.level
            when 1 then t1.userreferenceid
            when 2 then t2.userreferenceid
            when 3 then t3.userreferenceid 
            when 4 then t4.userreferenceid
         end referenceid,
         level.level
     from 
         member_details t0
     left outer join 
         member_details t1 on t1.referenceid = t0.userreferenceid
     left outer join 
         member_details t2 on t2.referenceid = t1.userreferenceid
     left outer join 
         member_details t3 on t3.referenceid = t2.userreferenceid
     left outer join 
         member_details t4 on t4.referenceid = t3.userreferenceid
     cross join 
         (select 1 level 
          union all
          select 2 
          union all
          select 3 
          union all
          select 4) level) t
where 
    t.referenceid is not null
```

Where my `refernceid` is the one which user uses to register (referalid), `userreferenceid` is the own id of the user (own referenceid).

For the above query my result set is displaying like this

```
user
ref
ere
nceid   GroupLevel Referenceid
-------------------------------------------
REF101  Level(1)    REF143
REF101  Level(2)    REF113
REF101  Level(3)    REF119
REF101  Level(3)    REF227
REF101  Level(4)    REF245
REF101  Level(4)    REF251
REF107  Level(1)    REF221
REF107  Level(1)    REF257
REF107  Level(2)    REF119
REF107  Level(2)    REF227
REF107  Level(3)    REF125
REF107  Level(3)    REF161
REF107  Level(4)    REF191
REF113  Level(3)    REF191
REF119  Level(1)    REF125
```

I need the result set exactly look like this.

I need to assign each and every refid and count of all users in level 1 ,2,3,4,

```
Userreferenceid  | Level1users|Level2Users|level3Users|Level4Users
-----------------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------
REF101                1            1           2           2
REF107                2            2           2           1
REF113                0            0           1           0
REF119                1            0           0           0
```

My table structure is

```
userreferenceid (varchar)   ||    referenceid(varchar)
```

Please help me out of this.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this
Aggregate summation

```
select Userreferenceid,
sum(case when GroupLevel='Level(1)' then 1 else 0 end) Level1users,
sum(case when GroupLevel='Level(2)' then 1 else 0 end) Level2users,
sum(case when GroupLevel='Level(3)' then 1 else 0 end) Level3users,
sum(case when GroupLevel='Level(4)' then 1 else 0 end) Level4users
from mytable group by Userreferenceid
```

Comment: your answer is correct when my table structure itself like my resultset in the second block .But iam getting that level when im executing the query

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by executing dynamic sql query also. If lot of `GroupLevel` values are there, then writing query would be hectic.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);

select @sql = stuff((
        select distinct 
        ', sum(case when [GroupLevel] = ' + char(39) + [GroupLevel] + char(39) 
        + ' then 1 else 0 end) as [' + replace(replace([GroupLevel], '(', ''), 
')', '') + 'Users]'
        from [your_table_name]
        for xml path('')
    )
    , 1, 2, ''
);

select @sql = 'select [userreferenceid], ' + @sql 
                + 'from [your_table_name] '
                + 'group by [userreferenceid];';

exec(@sql);
```

Comment: GroupLevel is not my column name. imgetting the result set only when im executing the same query i mentioned above